# how to pass list of objects in to controller method in MVC4?

Tags: c#, javascript, javaquery

i have list of objects :

```
var things = [];
var obj = {
            ayah: line.ayah,
            surah: line.surah,
            verse: line.verse
          };
          things.push(obj); 

$.ajax({
         method: 'GET',
         url: "Gateway/Inbound_Request_Handler?action=1",
         data:things,
         success: function (Data) {
         var mera_obj = Data.key;
         document.getElementById("Param2").value = '(' + mera_obj.Response_Code + ' , ' + mera_obj.Response_Description + ')';
         },
         error: function () {
         alert("ERROR: can't connect to Server this time");
                   }
               });
```

and class :

```
public class thing {
        public int surah { get; set; }
        public int ayah { get; set; }
        public string verse { get; set; }

    }
```

and here is controller method :

```
public class GatewayController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Inbound_Request_Handler(List<thing> things)
        {...}
    }
```

but its still showing that list in controller method is null. i don't know whats wrong with me ?

Comment: please suggest me anything...

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call specifies `data`

Change `data:things` to `data: {things: things}` to specify the name of the object passed in, so MVC can bind to it.

Comment: i am new to this place, no_reputation yet, here you go.! (Y)